# How to read barcodes from camera on .NET Compact Framework?

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, barcode

Looking for a solid solution for handling reading barcodes from Windows Mobile devices using .NET Compact Framework.

Ideally something open source or free, but not against paying for something that works well. I'm looking for a high quality solution if one is available.

Answer (score 0):

There are many forms of barcodes, and the open source [ZXing](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/) project covers several formats, including 2D and 1D barcodes.  While the project is Java-oriented, there is also some pure C# code which you might find helpful on .NET Compact.